# getting text from an array of buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, gettext

I'm trying to use an actionlistener in an array of buttons to change the color of the button then set the string value of the pressed button into the String called Letters. My issue is under my action performed section, the error i'm receiving is "Cannot find Symbol Symbol: getText()

this is the code for adding the actionlistener

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(Alphabet[i]));
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new Pick());
        alphabetWindow.add(buttons[i]);
    }
```

the code for when the button is pressed.

```
 static class Pick implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();//gets which button was pressed
        ((Component) source).setBackground(Color.green);
        Letter = ((Component) source).getText();
    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please consider adding stacktrace

Comment: Or use the actionCommand property of the ActionEvent which is defaulted to the text of the button which generated the event

Answer (score 1):

Or use the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionEvent` which is defaulted to the text of the button which generated the event

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();//gets which button was pressed
        ((Component) source).setBackground(Color.green);
        Letter = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downcast the source to a `button`. It is impossible for the IDE to infer that you want the method to be called in a deeper class on the class hierarchy.

```
static class Pick implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();//gets which button was pressed
        ((JButton) source).setBackground(Color.green);
        Letter = ((JButton) source).getText();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Component#getText()` does not exist and that's the reason why you're receiving the error. Just cast `source` to a `JButton` instead.

```
Letter = ((JButton) source).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Component is a superclass of many controls including buttons and doesn't have the method getText(). You should try something like:

```
Letter = ((JButton) source).getText();
```